# How do I get the UPDATE statements that were executed in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the details of an UPDATE statement that was executed in MS SQL to determine how records were suspiciously updated. The details include the time of execution, number of rows updated and if possible any info on the user that executed it.

Comment: Take a look at Extended Events. If you're trying to get historic queries, unless you have something set up before hand, it's unlikely you'll find out. You *might* find something in the default trace, but chances are probably low. You need to have the logging set up *before* the event.

Comment: ... or you could possibly examine Transaction log, not sure what "details" you need.
See fn_dblog

Comment: @MojoDBA I notice that the [Begin Time] contains null values. That would make it almost impossible to get the date and time of update statements executed.

Comment: @JaimeDolorjr. - it might not be trivial and you would have to do some digging - depending on how busy your db is and log truncation.
Look for LOP_BEGIN_XACT and LOP_COMMIT_XACT - there should be dates, and filter on AllocUnit ID or NAME; if you know page IDs of the new data - even better, it'll help you narrow down your result.

Comment: @MojoDBA I'll check them out. Much obliged